# Изменить атрибут src тега img

Tags: javascript

Как можно убрать **www.example.ru** из **src**?

```html
<textarea id="content" cols="60" rows="10">
    <div id="description"><div style="text-align: center;">

        <img alt="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" border="0"
            src="www.example.ru/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg"
            title="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности">

        <img alt="Пожарная безопасность в школе" border="0"
            src="www.example.ru/images/goods/pb_foto_2.jpg"
            title="Пожарная безопасность в школе">
    </div>

    <img src="cat.jpg">
</textarea>
```

Comment: через id используя jquery я могу сделать, но как поменять сразу у всех сооброжалки не хватает.

Comment: так же как и через id, только для выборки использовать класс или тег

Comment: А зачем там у вам `<textarea>` открывается и не закрывается? Менять хотите внутри `textarea`?

Comment: Одного `</div>` не хватает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно добавить id="needtodelete" у элемента и будет так

```
<textarea id="content" cols="60" rows="10">
<div id="description"><div style="text-align: center;">
<img id="needtodelete" alt="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" border="0" src="www.example.ru/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg" title="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" />  
<img alt="Пожарная безопасность в школе" border="0" src="www.example.ru/images/goods/pb_foto_2.jpg" title="Пожарная безопасность в школе" />  
</div>
```

и потом
в скрипте :

```
var a=document.getElementById("needtodelete");
a.src=a.src.replace(/www.example.ru/g,"");
```

или ещё можно удалить до первого вхождения знака '/'

Comment: chrome пишет "Cannot read property  'src' of null "

Comment: вероятно вы где-то ошиблись в имени id и в переменную а уходит null ...

Comment: вы оказались правы, но src не поменялось.
www.example.ru/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg

Comment: @votanko у меня всё отрабатывает, в коде возможно мешает textarea , с ним у меня не находит картинку, потому-что он становиться текстом

Comment: var test = $('img').attr('src').replace('www.example.ru/', '/');
$('img').attr('src', test);
Сделал так, отработало, однако все картинки стали одинаковыми.
Можно ли как нибудь доработать этот код?

Comment: @votanko я же внизу написал используй "var a=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
    if (a[i].className=="classname123")
        {
            a[i].src=...            
        }
    }" для прохода по всем имеджам предварительно добавив класс к нужным имеджам

Comment: @votanko вместо $('img') должен быть нужный объект тогда будут редактироваться не все

Answer (score 1):

вы писали

> через id используя jquery я могу сделать, но как поменять сразу у всех
>   сооброжалки не хватает.

можно добавить класс "classname123" у каждого такого элемента и тогда

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
    if (a[i].className=="classname123")
        {
            a[i].src=...            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У всех тегов `<img>` в документе поменять в атрибуте `src` подстроку можно примерно так:

```js
Array
  .prototype
  .forEach  // спасибо @Grundy
  .call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    function(e) {
      e.src = e.src.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?www.example.ru\/?/ig, '');
    }
  )
;
```

```html
<div id="description">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img alt="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" border="0" src="www.example.ru/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg" title="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" />
    <img alt="Пожарная безопасность в школе" border="0" src="www.example.ru/images/goods/pb_foto_2.jpg" title="Пожарная безопасность в школе" />
  </div>

  <img src="cat.jpg">
```

В вашем вопросе код для замены находится внутри тега `textarea`, что делает весь этот `html` просто-текстом. Тогда менять нужно регуляркой, включающей в себя `src=`, и, опционально, проверкой, что строка "src" находится внутри «тега» `<img>`. Без лишних проверок:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("content");
el.innerHTML = el
  .innerHTML
  .replace(/(src=")www.example.ru/ig, "$1")
;
```

```html
<textarea id="content" cols="60" rows="10">
    <div id="description"><div style="text-align: center;">

        <img alt="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" border="0"
            src="www.example.ru/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg"
            title="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности">

        <img alt="Пожарная безопасность в школе" border="0"
            src="www.example.ru/images/goods/pb_foto_2.jpg"
            title="Пожарная безопасность в школе">
    </div>

    <img src="cat.jpg">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Чёт у меня не работает. Скорее всего потому что в `textarea` элементы нельзя найти. Всё что внутри является текстом

Comment: тут лучше forEach так как нужно изменить элементы, а не получить новую коллекцию

Comment: @Grundy не лучше, т.к. ES5 и может не поддерживаться некоторыми браузерами, в отличие от `.map()`. Элементы [прекрасно меняются](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/o5zc9xcf/).

Comment: @Sergiks, `map`  и `forEach` функции из одного набора, если работает одна - работает и другая, главное отличие в том, что `forEach` новый массив не создает. в отличие от `map`

Comment: Точно, `.map()`, тоже из ES5 : (  Думал, он древний. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Например так на jQuery:

```
function parseUrl( url ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
}

$("img[src]").each(function () {
    var link = parseUrl($(this).attr("src"));
  var output = link.pathname + link.search + link.hash;
  $(this).attr("src", output);
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeev9oqj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Просто

```js
textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.innerHTML = textarea.innerHTML.replace(/(http|www).*ru\//ig, '');
```

```html
<textarea id="content" cols="60" rows="10">
    <div id="description"><div style="text-align: center;">

        <img alt="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности" border="0"
            src="https://www.example.ru/images/goods/umey_deystvovat.jpg"
            title="Стенд и картинки для уголка безопасности">

        <img alt="Пожарная безопасность в школе" border="0"
            src="www.example.ru/images/goods/pb_foto_2.jpg"
            title="Пожарная безопасность в школе">
    </div>

    <img src="cat.jpg">
</textarea>
```